# Marking an NPM module as deprecated in a single project

Tags: npm, enzyme

My team and I have a large collection of [Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) tests in a project and we have recently decided to use [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) moving forward.

We want to convert older Enzyme tests to RTL over time, so we're looking for a way to mark Enzyme as deprecated within our project. Are there any out-of-the-box options available?

We could wrap Enzyme functions in wrappers, then mark them as deprecated:

```js
// enzyme.js
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';

/** @deprecated use React Testing Library instead */
export const mount = Enzyme.mount;
```

```js
// some test
import { mount } from './enzyme';
```

But this means we have to update all instances of the Enzyme import, and we're hoping there's a simpler solution available.

Comment: If the team's aligned on this change do you need it to be marked as deprecated? Catch any new tests using Enzyme or failures to cut over when touching existing tests through  your existing review processes (pairing, PR review, whatever).

Comment: The issue is that the project is rather large and we have new joiners all the time that may fall into this trap. Yes, we ca probably catch these in review, but by that point the cost is already incurred. Having a handy strikethrough in the IDE to highlight it is deprecated will at least trigger the question if Enzyme is ok to use and hopefully reduce that feedback loop.